# Finding the PostgreSQL PITR recovery point

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to find the query xid or lsn at the point I want to recover?
I checked the WAL file using pg_waldump, but could not find it. Should I check it in another way?

I know the delete query. So I want to find and recover the XID from the point before the delete query.

Comment: What is the condition that determines that you have found the correct location? You have to know to which point you want to recover, nobody else can tell you that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbeI know the delete query. So I want to find and recover the XID from the point before the delete query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then `pg_xlogdump` is your friend. You may need to hire a professional who can interpret the output, since it contains low-level binary information.